# AVRO : Keeping union record field names when using union record type

Tags: java, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka-streams to transform xml messages to avro format. I would like to know if it is possible to keep the field names of my union records when using union type for records in my avro schema as in the example below so that instead of having the name "main_record", i would have "record1" or "record2" in my avro message depending on the input data i am receiving:

```
    {
    "namespace": "proj.avro",
    "protocol": "app_messages",
    "doc" : "application messages",
    "name": "myRecord",
    "type" : "record",
    "fields": [
    {
    "name": "main_record",
    "type": [
        {
            "name": "record1",
            "type" : "record", 
            "fields": 
            [
                {
                    "name" : "request_id", 
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "message_type",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "users",
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "record2",
            "type" : "record",
            "fields" :
            [
                {
                    "name" : "request_id",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "response_code",
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "response_count",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "reason_code",
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
    ]
}
```